# Building ffmpeg for Android with clang

Tags: android, ffmpeg, clang

I'm trying to build ffmpeg for Android using Clang and Android NDK 20 in Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying:

```
./configure
--prefix=android/
--disable-asm
--enable-cross-compile
--disable-static
--disable-programs
--disable-doc
--enable-shared
--enable-protocol=file
--enable-pic
--enable-small
--disable-pthreads
--ar=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar
--strip=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-strip
--ld=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld
--cc=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
--cxx=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++
--as=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
--target-os=android
--extra-cflags=-target aarch64-none-linux-android
-mfpu=neon
-mfloat-abi=soft
-I/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android
-O3
-fPIC
--extra-ldflags=-L/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x
-L/platforms/android-/arch-arm64/usr/lib
--sysroot=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot
```

But I'm getting some compile errors like this:

```
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: error: expected identifier or '('
char* getenv(const char* __name);
      ^
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:18: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
                 ^
In file included from libavdevice/alldevices.c:23:
In file included from ./libavformat/internal.h:27:
In file included from ./libavformat/avformat.h:319:
In file included from ./libavcodec/avcodec.h:31:
In file included from ./libavutil/samplefmt.h:24:
In file included from ./libavutil/avutil.h:296:
In file included from ./libavutil/common.h:39:
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: error: expected ')'
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:18: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
                 ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: note: to match this '('
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:17: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
                ^
In file included from libavdevice/alldevices.c:23:
In file included from ./libavformat/internal.h:27:
In file included from ./libavformat/avformat.h:319:
In file included from ./libavcodec/avcodec.h:31:
In file included from ./libavutil/samplefmt.h:24:
In file included from ./libavutil/avutil.h:296:
In file included from ./libavutil/common.h:39:
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: error: expected ')'
char* getenv(const char* __name);
      ^
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:24: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
                       ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: note: to match this '('
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
               ^
In file included from libavdevice/fbdev_dec.c:37:
In file included from ./libavutil/internal.h:42:
In file included from ./libavutil/timer.h:41:
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: error: expected identifier or '('
char* getenv(const char* __name);
      ^
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:18: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
                 ^
In file included from libavdevice/fbdev_dec.c:37:
In file included from ./libavutil/internal.h:42:
In file included from ./libavutil/timer.h:41:
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: error: expected ')'
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:18: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
                 ^
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: note: to match this '('
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
```

I also tried, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339191/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-for-android-with-clang-in-ubuntu18-04):

```
./configure
--prefix=/home/deps/build/ffmpeg/arm64
--cross-prefix=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android-
--sysroot=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot
--disable-static
--disable-doc
--disable-ffmpeg
--disable-ffplay
--disable-ffprobe
--disable-symver
--enable-shared
--enable-protocol=concat
--enable-protocol=file
--enable-muxer=mp4
--enable-demuxer=mpegts
--target-os=android
--enable-decoder=h264
--enable-cross-compile
--arch=aarch64
--toolchain=clang-usan
--extra-cflags=-fPIE
-fPIC
-ffast-math
-funroll-loops
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-mfpu=vfpv3-d16
--extra-ldflags=-pie
--ar=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar
--strip=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-strip
--ld=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld
--cc=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
--cxx=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++
--as=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
```

But I get this error:

```
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.
```

In the log file I get:

```
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --sysroot=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot -fsanitize=undefined -fPIE -fPIC -ffast-math -funroll-loops -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -c -o /tmp/ffconf.knsd57OI/test.o /tmp/ffconf.knsd57OI/test.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfloat-abi=softfp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld -pie -fsanitize=undefined --sysroot=/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/sysroot -o /tmp/ffconf.knsd57OI/test /tmp/ffconf.knsd57OI/test.o
/home/sources/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld: -f may not be used without -shared
C compiler test failed.
```

It looks like, by the line `-fsanitize=undefined` that an undefined is being passed, I don't know why.

Anyone knows what's happening or an alternative way to build?